# To get the latest post and comments of a facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I want to get latest post and comments from a particular page.

The below code gets all the posts and comments of that page using graph api explorer:

```js
 var accessToken = hdnaccesstoken.Value;//page access token
 var client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
 dynamic result = client.Get("me", new { fields = "name,id,posts" });
```

My requirement is to get the latest(30 mins for example) posts and comments. How can I be able to achieve that?

Comment: you can't achieve that with graph api, use FQL instead, where you can query the posts by created_time

Comment: As I want to access my pages post, in FQL there is a table for page but I don't see any 'post' column in that table, even created_time column does not exists. You can refer the columns of page table here:https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page

Comment: You must query the STREAM table and add a where clause where actor_id = YOUR_PAGE_ID https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream

Comment: As I was going through your above link I found that actor_id is not an indexable column, I sorted the other way around by using source_id=MY_PAGE_ID. But still I cannot find the posts column in stream table as well.

Comment: oh sorry about that, the Stream is a FQL table that can be used to return a list of a stream posts.

Comment: Yes you are right, but dude your comment was really helpful. I worked around and got the solution....   This belongs to getting the post SELECT post_id,message  FROM stream WHERE source_id = PAGE_ID and for getting the comments it is SELECT  text from comment where post_id in (SELECT post_id FROM stream 
WHERE source_id = PAGE_ID)

Answer (score 0):

What you'll want to try is to use [field expansion](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/field_expansion/). This will allow you to limit results by number.

I'm not sure what SDK you are using, but with a raw request to the Graph API, you'll want to do something similar to this :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID?fields=id,name,posts.limit(10)
```

This will limit the number of posts returned to the last (most recent) 10 results. You can test this out with the [Graph Api Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname%2Cposts.limit%2810%29).

Comment: I am using the Facebook SDK 6.4.2

Comment: Actually I meant what language the SDK is in :P

Comment: Ah... well I have no experience with the C# SDK or C# at all :P My method should be possible no matter what SDK you use...